# Potential energy density of a fluid in motion

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, potential-energy, density

If I have a fluid in motion at a given time and I know its pressure $p$ everywhere, I know its dynamic viscosity $\mu$ and I know its velocity field $\vec V$.

This system must hold some intrinsic potential energy $E$.

I know that in a fluid at rest the pressure is a measurement of potential energy, so if the fluid is either static or has uniform velocity then I should just get:

$$\Psi(x) = p(x)$$

I.e. the energy density at a given point is just the pressure.

However, if the velocity gradient is not uniform, then there must be potential energy dependent on both the velocity gradient at a point and the viscosity of the fluid.

What should the energy density be in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for an [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state) (EOS); for instance, an ideal gas follows,
$$p=\rho e(\gamma-1)$$
where $p$ is the pressure, $\rho$ the density, $e$ the specific internal energy and $\gamma$ the adiabatic index.

As far as I know, there isn't an EOS that uses the viscosity, which should make sense since it is not a [state variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function). It only plays a role in the dynamic evolution via the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations).

Comment: Is there not a way I could express the dynamic evolution as an equation of state nonetheless? 

From a high level, it is clear that if one looks at a specific time, the fluid in motion has energy contained into it, and that this energy is dependent on it;s internal velocity field and viscoscity. As time passes this energy will dissipate as heat. 
So if the fluid has energy at a given time one should be able to describe the energy, no?

Comment: No, the "dynamic evolution" I mention is time-evolution of the fluid system as solved by the Navier-Stokes PDE. The EOS relates pressure, density, temperature, energy, etc. While you use the EOS as a [closure condition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/717990/25301), the two are separate things.